# How to choose a value between the two, with given probability in Excel?

Tags: excel, statistics, probability

I have list of probabilities in column 1. How I can fill column 2 with 0 and 1 based on the corresponding probabilities?

```
0.5 1
0.2 0
0.9 1
0.35 1
0.1 0
```

Comment: generate random number with RAND from 0 to 1, compare with the probability. If it is bigger then it is 0, else 1. There may be a more elegant way tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comments;

> generate random number with RAND from 0 to 1, compare with the probability. If it is bigger then it is 0, else 1.

```
 =IF(RAND()>=A1,0,1)
```

Comment: Just a very slight reservation, it is possible for RAND() to be zero, so if you set A1 to zero you would very occasionally get a 1.